# Excel: counting content between dates

Tags: excel, countif

I'd like to count cells that contain "/" or "\" that are less than a date I set.

To check / and \ I have:

`=COUNTIF('Attendance Data'!7:7,"/")+COUNTIF('Attendance Data'!7:7,"\")`

To check dates I have:

`=COUNTIF('Attendance Data'!2:2,"<"&D3)` D3 is the date I set.

How does one combine these into an AND statement?

i.e. Only count cells that contain / or \ and are older than said date.

Thanx for looking,
Sam

Comment: You use COUNTIFS.

Comment: When I use =COUNTIFS('Attendance Data'!7:7,"/",'Attendance Data'!7:7,"\") I get zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could use [countifs](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/countifs-function-dda3dc6e-f74e-4aee-88bc-aa8c2a866842)

`=COUNTIFS('Attendance Data'!7:7,"/",'Attendance Data'!2:2,"<"&D3)+COUNTIFS('Attendance Data'!7:7,"\",'Attendance Data'!2:2,"<"&D3)`

Comment: Thanx. It's been a long day.